# Multiple bodies with same fixture

Tags: c++, box2d

I am trying to make a Box2D simulation of a Rover with 4 tyres. I have given same fixture to all the tyres. So this is better or different fixtures for different bodies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make copies of this fixture. Fixture lives only when it is attached to a body, which means it is a real object, not only description of a shape. That is why you need a distinct one for each tyre in each rover.